# With JPA/JPQL is it possible to manually load and Entity with its OneToMany Association?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Suppose I have 2 entities, `Parent` and `Child`, where the parent contains 1..n children:

```java
@Entity
@Data @NoArgsConstructor
public class Parent {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String basic;
    private String detail;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

    public Parent(String basic, String detail, Set<Child> children) {...}
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Data @NoArgsConstructor
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private long id;
    private String basic;
    private String detail;

    public Child(String basic, String detail) {...}
}
```

I can load Parent-entities by using a JpaRepository:

```java
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> { }

// in Controller or Service
List<Parent> parents = parentRepository.findAll();
```

I'm trying to use projections. For this reason I want to know if it is possible to manually load the parents with a Query, so that i could only load needed data. In a perfect world this could look something like this:

```java
// Dtos, the String detail is not required for both Parent and Child
@Value
public class ParentDto {
    long id;
    String basic;
    Collection<Child> children;

    public ParentDto(long id, String basic, Collection<ChildDto> children) {...}
}

@Value
public class ChildDto {
    long id;
    String basic;

    public ChildDto(long id, String basic) {...}
}
```

and

```java
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {
    // Projection - *NOT WORKING*, this is what i would like
    @Query("select p.id, p.basic, p.children.id, p.children.basic from Parent p")
    List<ParentDto> findAllProjected();
}
```

This obviously fails, because it will join the all parents with their child, resulting in amount_of_parents * amount_of_their_children rows. The ParentDto would need a contrustor `public ParentDto(long id, String basic, ChildDto child) {...}`, so i had n ParentDtos per parent where n is the number of children the parent has.

Do i have to manually group the rows by the parents Id's and collect the ChildDtos together? Can I solve this using a subselect? I know Jpa solves this by selecting the parents and doing 1 select for each parent, fetching their children (when i use the autogenerated repository method). I was really hoping that projections/views would be much easier as they are such a fundamental requirement for me and most likely many other applications. Having to always load all data, load only the wanted data - but without their associations or having to load the associations manually for each entity seems like a bumper.

Note: i did try InterfaceProjection but do not want to use it due to it loading all data and stripping away unnessecary parts only when serializing it to json.

Thanks in regards!